# Concentric rings on a snub square tiling

Tags: code-golf, sequence, combinatorics, tiling

This challenge takes place on the [snub square tiling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snub_square_tiling).

Start by choosing any triangle, and color it \$c_1\$.
Next, find all tiles which touch this triangle at any vertex, and color them \$c_2\$. Next, find all tiles which share a vertex with any \$c_2\$-colored tile, and color these \$c_3\$.
Continue this process ad infinitum.

## Illustration

[image: Concentric tiling on snub square tiling]

## Initial terms

The sequence begins

```
  a(1) = 1
  a(2) = 9
  a(3) = 21
  a(4) = 35
```

Notice:

- `a(1) = 1` corresponds to the red triangle;
- `a(2) = 9` corresponds to the number of tiles in the second, orange layer;
- `a(3) = 21` corresponds to the number of tiles in the third, green layer; and so on.

(Note, this [sequence is now in the OEIS](https://oeis.org/A332019); OEIS sequence [A296368](https://oeis.org/A296368) is closely related.)

## Challenge

Your goal is to write a program that takes in a positive integer `n` and returns the number of tiles that are colored \$c_n\$, (i.e. the number of tiles in the \$n\$-th layer.) This is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) challenge, so the shortest code in bytes wins.

Comment: This looks like a lion! +1

Comment: Can this be zero indexed?

Comment: @JoKing, I'd like to keep it one-indexed—partly because folks have already submitted solutions with that assumption.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 8 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
’3cạ×ʋ12
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9Rw0zj5Ie7Fh6efqrb0Oj///@mAA)**

#### How?

```
’3cạ×ʋ12 - Link: integer, n
’        - decrement              (n-1)                1   2   3   4   5   6   7  ...
      12 - twelve                 12                  12  12  12  12  12  12 12  ...
     ʋ   - dyad:
 3       -   three                3                    3   3   3   3   3   3   3  ...
  c      -   choose               3C(n-1)              1   3   3   1   0   0   0  ...
    ×    -   multiply             (n-1)*12             0  12  24  36  48  60  72  ...
   ạ     -   absolute difference  |3C(n-1)-(n-1)*12|   1   9  21  35  48  60  72  ...
```

Comment: Ah, cool that Jelly has a way to avoid duplicating `’`. I still have no idea how any of it works =p

Comment: Yeah even with Lynn's excellent tutorial and its [Chains](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jellylanguage/wiki/Tutorial#4chains) section, it's still a tricky beast :)

Answer (score 26):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 26 bytes

```ruby
->n{~-n*12-496/4**n%4+1/n}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y6vuk43T8vQSNfE0kzfREsrT9VE21A/r/a/hqGenqGBpl5uYkF1TWZNgUJ0pk5adGZsbO1/AA)

Revised version adding `1/n` and subtracting `496/4**n%4` to get the `+1,-3,-3,-1` offset for the first 4 terms.

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 32 bytes

```ruby
->n{n>4?~-n*12:[0,1,9,21,35][n]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y6vOs/OxL5ON0/L0Mgq2kDHUMdSx8hQx9g0Njovtva/hqGenqGBpl5uYkF1TWZNgUJ0pk5adGYsUAoA)

After 4, the sequence settles down to `(n-1)*12`. See diagram below (the equilateral triangles have been distorted into 45 degree isosceles triangles and the entire diagram rotated 45 degrees, but it remains topologically equivalent.)

[image]

Comment: Really nice job :D

Comment: Well done on finding a way to simplify the topology and providing a closed formula for `n>4`!

Answer (score 9):

## JavaScript (ES6), 23 bytes

Based on [Level River St's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/198953/58563).

```javascript
n=>[1,5,13,7][--n]^n*12
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/P1i7aUMdUx9BYxzw2Wlc3LzYuT8vQ6H9afpFGnoKtgqG1Qp6CDZA2ADK0tTUVqrkUFJLz84rzc1L1cvLTNRISNVSq82o1gWpVqtM08jRrEzStuWr/AwA)

#### How?

We compute \$(n-1)\times12\$ and adjust the first 4 values with a XOR.

$$\begin{array}{c|c}
n&1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10\\
\hline
(n-1)\times12&0&12&24&36&48&60&72&84&96&108\\
\hline
\text{XOR}&1&5&13&7&\color{grey}0&\color{grey}0&\color{grey}0&\color{grey}0&\color{grey}0&\color{grey}0\\
\hline
a(n)&1&9&21&35&48&60&72&84&96&108
\end{array}$$

Answer (score 9):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 9 bytes

```
<©12*3®cα
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f5tBKQyMt40Prks9t/P/fGAA) or [try a test suite](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/R/i7mevpKBrp6Bk7/ff5tBKQyMt40Prks9t/K/zHwA).

```
<           # input - 1
 ©          # save to register
  12*       # multiply by 12
      ®     # push the register
     3 c    # binomial coefficient(3, input - 1)
        α   # absolute difference
```

With 0-indexing, this would be 7 bytes:

```
12*3Icα
```

Answer (score 7):

## [Python](https://docs.python.org/3/), 31 bytes

```python
lambda n:n*12-11-(n>4or 5%-n%5)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcrNCkBAFAbQV/lSakZmcf1sFC@CxYjhFtc02UiefTjr4@9rO6WMDi2GuNtjmi2kkYwKQ2SUdNUZUKdG0lrH3geWS7nk4Remw@MU6zfRcH9isCBYWRdFeUF6jB8)

Answer (score 5):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 14 bytes<sup>SBCS</sup>

```apl
12(|×-3!⍨⊢)-∘1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///39BIo@bwdF1jxUe9Kx51LdLUfdQxw/B/2qO2CY96@x71TfX0f9TVfGi98aO2iUBecJAzkAzx8Az@n3ZoxaPezYYGAA)

Direct translation of [Jonathan Allan's Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/198961/78410). Even the code structure is the same. Jelly is a golfy descendant of APL; if you want to learn Jelly, learn APL first!

#### How it works

```apl
12(|×-3!⍨⊢)-∘1  ⍝ Monadic train, input: n
12(       )-∘1  ⍝ Pass on to the inner function with left←12 and right←n-1
    ×             ⍝ left × right
     -            ⍝ minus
      3!⍨⊢        ⍝ binomial(3, right)
   |              ⍝ absolute value of the above
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>15</s> 9 bytes

```
’3cạ×12$Ʋ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AS8A0P9qZWxsef//4oCZM2PhuqHDlzEyJMay/zvigJwgLT4g4oCdO8OHCjEww4figqxZ/w)

A monadic link taking \$n\$ as its argument and returning \$a(n)\$.

Based on [@LevelRiverSt’s clever Ruby answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/198953/58563) so be sure to upvote that one too!

Thanks to @Grimmy for saving 6 bytes!

### Explanation

```
 ’       | Subtract 1
       Ʋ | Following as a monad
3c       | - Number of ways of picking (n-1) items from 3
  ạ   $  | - Absolute difference from:
   ×12   |   - Multiply (n-1) × 12
```

Comment: [Here’s 9 bytes](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9Rw0zj5Ie7FgLpw9MNjY51/bd@1DBHQddO4VHDXOvD7VyGBofbHzWtifwPAA)

Comment: @Grimmy thanks! I’d missed that because of the difference for n=1 being -1, though of course with absolute difference that doesn’t matter.

Comment: @Grimmy I was trying to golf exactly that, and now managed it :)

Answer (score 4):

## brainfuck, 50 bytes

```
>>>>>>+<++<<----<+<,-[>++++++++++++[[>+<-]<]>>-]>.
```

Does i/o as raw byte values, like the others here.

Comment: You can remove leading `>>` by using the implementation available on [TIO](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9f204XCOzstLXttG1AQEc3GshBgGgg10Y31ibWzk431k7v/38uAA).

Comment: That's a nonstandard language extension that I'd like to see stamped out. I'm not a fan of the fragmentation of brainfuck into incompatible dialects, and I work against that where I can.

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 26 bytes

```perl6
{$_*12-[-1,3,3,1][$_]}o*-1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYKvwv1olXsvQSDda11DHGAgNY6NV4mNr87V0Df9bcxUnViroAdWl5RcpGOrpGRr8BwA)

If this could be zero-indexed the `o*-1` at the end can be removed. Returns `(n-1)*12`, offsetting the first 4 values.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <strike>40</strike> 36 bytes

```python
lambda n:~-n*12-(*n*[0],1,3,3,-1)[4]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcJBCoMwEAXQq3xcJSGBjnYl2IukWUQ0dkBHCW5E9OqxvLcd@2@VpiR0@JY5Lv0QIe3txFDtlBHjX8GSbf4caf8OxW@ZZVepOvmC@@BMivVVaaQ1g8GCHGUaFVkiHcoD)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 39 bytes

```python
lambda n:n>4and~-n*12or[1,9,21,35][n-1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFBCoMwEAXQqwyukhIXk9RFBb2IuphiYwfaHwluRPTq8b11374JocRuLD/5v2chtOifgvmq8WCf8sDu5Ty70EwDap5KTJmUFJQFy8ewY7btmhWbiZWYQ09LHR3RqD0rW24)

Total rip of [Level River St](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/15599/level-river-st)'s answer so upvote him.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python](https://docs.python.org/3/), 38 bytes

```python
lambda n:n*12-11-([1]*n+[2,4,4,0])[-n]
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYlLCoAgFAD3neLt0lLoVRAEdRFzYZQV1DPMTae3z8xqmPMOq6Mq2m6IuznGyQC1lGEpESVTqDPKVSnq10JzJUlH6zyE@QqwEXhDy8xQADa8TeDl9BsF9n0BqexTAfYvzuMD)**

Answer (score 2):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 14 bytes

```
12(*|@-3!~])<:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/DY00tGocdI0V62I1baz@a3IpcKUmZ@QraFinaSqo2SkYamfqGRr8BwA)

A [J](http://jsoftware.com/) port of [Bubbler's APL answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/198966/75681), so it's also a port of [Jonathan Allan's Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/198961/78410).

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <sup><s>34</s> <s>33</s></sup> 32 bytes

Saved a byte thanks to [Grimmy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/6484/grimmy)!!!

```c
f(n){n=--n<4?"!)5C"[n]-32:n*12;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9NI0@zOs9WVzfPxsReSVHT1FkpOi9W19jIKk/L0Mi69n9uYmaehmZ1Wn6RRmZeiUKmrYG1tnamjZGhdUERUCBNQ0k1RUHXTkE1JSZPSSdTJ00jU1NTE6gRAA)

Comment: [32](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9NI0@zOs9WVzfPxsReSVHT1FkpOi9W19jIKk/L0Mi69n9uYmaehmZ1Wn6RRmZeiUKmrYG1tnamjZGhdUERUCBNQ0k1RUHXTkE1JSZPSSdTJ00jU1NTE6gRAA)

Comment: @Grimmy Nice - takes care of all the `n-1`s with a decrement  up front. Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 1):

## brainfuck, 78 bytes

```
++++[->+++<]>>>+>--->--->-<<<<<<,-[->>>[+]<[->+<]<[->+>+<<]<[->+<]>]>>[->+<]>.
```

You can try it online over at [TIO](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/p@bmptfVGnFlZlXoFCjYGgEJBKTk0FMIM5LTVcwRqNB4gZQnFqSnFqSWpT4XxsIonXtgKRNrJ2dnbadrq4uBNuAgY4uUNbOLlo71gakzAZCARk2MAE7oD4oS@//fy4A) (the input is a line-feed (ascii 10) and the output is an `l` (ascii 108))

You can also try the verbose code at [this](https://copy.sh/brainfuck/?c=KysrK1stPisrKzxdIHNldCB1cCAxMgo-Pj4rPi0tLT4tLS0-LSBzZXQgdXAgdGhlIHNoaWZ0cwo8PDw8PDwgYmFjayBhdCAwCiwKbWVtb3J5IGF0IHRoaXMgcG9pbnQgKHBvaW50ZXIgaXMgYXQgdGhlIGxlZnQpCmlucCB8IDEyIHwgMCAoYWNjdW11bGF0b3IpIHwgMSB8IG5lZyAzIHwgbmVnIDMgfCBuZWcgMSB8IDAgfCAwIHwgZXRjZXRlcmEKLSBzdWJ0cmFjdCAxIGZyb20gbiBmaXJzdApbIHdoaWxlIHRoZXJlIGlzIHNvbWUgaW5wdXQKLSBkZWNyZW1lbnQgaXQuCj4-PlsrXSB6ZXJvIG91dCB0aGUgbmV4dCBzaGlmdAo8Wy0-KzxdIG1vdmUgdGhlIG91dHB1dCBvbmUgY2VsbCBmb3J3YXJkCjxbLT4rPis8PF0gbW92ZSB0aGUgMTIgZm9yd2FyZCBhbmQgYWxzbyBhZGQgaXQgdG8gdGhlIG91dHB1dAo8Wy0-KzxdPiBtb3ZlIHRoZSBpbnB1dCBvbmUgY2VsbCBmb3J3YXJkCl0KPj4KWy0-KzxdIGFkZCBvdXRwdXQgdG8gb2Zmc2V0Cj4uIHByaW50IG91dHB1dA$$) online interpreter where input can be inserted as decimals, e.g. `\6` gives 6 as input. After running, you can hit the "view memory" button and check the value of the output cell in bold, to ensure the result is right.

Answer (score 1):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 61 bytes

```
,-[>++<-[>+++<-[>+++>++<<-[>+++>+<<-[>+++<-]]]]]>[>++++<-]>+.
```

Input/output as character codes ([meta](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/18027/6484)).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fRzfaTlvbBkzCKJAAnGkDl4sFATswB8Sz09b7/58LAA) or [try it with decimal I/O](https://tio.run/##dVBBCsMwDHuQl152FfqI8aEbDMagh8Hen8pum22wCeLEtiwluTzn@3J7XR@d5t6CWic3b2941qzg2EpsoRPgjbQBICguYGQoRAQCXQLqVTy2LIwjRi8SrCQzWv@Wl50xydJnXjJNKkOh7BU@hzTzfyI2vu8D2d4hwpQPsWQEvHRwfEMbDpKYioGfEmrltdMV/bwC).

Comment: Good work on this one!

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 10 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
Å²@8Ω@╩vä3
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=8ffd4038ea40ca768433&i=1%0A2%0A3%0A4&m=2)

Answer (score 0):

## Rust - 52 bytes

```
let m=|n|(match n{1=>1,2=>9,3=>21,4=>35,_=>n}-1)*12;
```

oh gosh.. it loses even to Brainf***